# Erro com rotas complementares no Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel, laravel-rotas

Inicialmente, criei a seguinte rota (1ª busca):

```php
Route::get('/buscar/profissoes/{city_id_slug?}', array('as' => 'neighborhoods.city', 
    'uses' => 'NeighborhoodsController@getIndexCity'));
```

Então a URL fica assim no final:

```
 http://example.com/buscar/profissoes/1-uberlandia
```

Após, criei a segund arota (2ª busca - continuação)

```php
Route::get('/buscar/profissionais/{city_id_slug}/{neighborhood_id_slug}/
{profession_id_slug}', array('as' => 'professionals.search', 'uses' => 'ProfessionalsController@getSearch'));
```

Então a URL deve ficar assim:

```
 http://example.com/buscar/profissionais/1-uberlandia/15-santa-monica/1-pedreiro
```

Mas como a URL acima é gerada dinamicamente, inicialmente ela não tem os últimos 2 parâmetros. Eles serão adicionados ao clicar em submit. De qualquer forma, adicionei os parâmetors, apenas como teste e não funcionou:

```php
URL::route('professionals.search', array($city_id_slug, $city_id_slug, $city_id_slug))
```

Então o Laravel retorna o seguinte:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Routing \ Exception \ RouteNotFoundException

Unable to generate a URL for the named route "http://example.com/buscar/profissionais/1-uberlandia/1-uberlandia/1-uberlandia" as such route does not exist.
```

Qual a maneira certa de fazer isso? E o que está errado nas minhas rotas, visando que são diferentes, e que mesmo forçando os 2 últimos parâmetros com o número 1, não funcionou?

Comment: Na segunda rota, o parametro neighborhood_id_slug não poderia, ou não deveria, ser opcional({neighborhood_id_slug?}).

Comment: Sim, já fiz assim também. Mas como eu estava fazendo um teste "forçando" os parâmetros com o valor 1, deixei obrigatória pra ver se iria acontecer o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode submeter via **POST** tudo para o "buscar":

```php
  cidade/{city_id_slug}/bairro/{neighborhood_id_slug?}/profissao/{profession_id_slug?}
```

E redirecionar para uma rota **GET** com a URL tratada.

Acredito que seja uma solução tranquila de ser implementada. E gera mais controle do que você estiver fazendo.

Comment: Creio que seja o melhor mesmo.

Comment: Você terá mais controle sobre a montagem da Rota dessa forma, passando os parâmetros de acordo com sua necessidade.

Answer (score 1):

Patrick,

Via laravel não será possível gerar a segunda rota corretamente sem os parâmetros.

Já precisei fazer algo do tipo, e o que fiz foi gerar a primeira parte(sua rota 1),
e adicionei manualmente via javascript (não tenho mais acesso ao projeto, por isso não tenho como postar o código pra solução do problema).

Dica: A 2ª rota deve vir primeiro, pois se ele encontrar o "padrão" pra primeira irá parar nela.

Comment: A primeira rota eu gero com javascript mesmo. Mas quanto a segunda, não consegui uma alternativa, tentei até isso: `URL::route('professionals.search', array($city_id_slug, 1, 1))` mas não funcionou.

Comment: Nesse padrão não terá como gerar dinamicamente via laravel, deverá ser via javascript mesmo, usará o laravel apenas para o "root_url()".

Answer (score 1):

Interprete cada rota como distinta, então você pode criar 3 rotas: uma que atende às solicitações com 1 parâmetro, outra com dois e outra com três...